# hasMany and belongsTo don't work?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations

I have a strange behavior with my linked models:

**User model:**

```
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Place' => array(
        'className' => 'Place',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

**Place model:**

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

When I do `$this->Place->find('all');` I see an empty array result, but when I remove the $belongsTo association, it finds places, but without any users of course. Where is the problem? Do I need to add a hasAndBelongsToMany association?

Here is all two models code:

**AdPlace:**

```
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * AdPlace Model
 *
 */
class AdPlace extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'AdPlace';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'url' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
            'urlUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Такой URL существует',
                'required' => 'create',
                'on' => 'create'
            ),
            'urlValidate' => array(
                'rule' => array('url', true), 
                'message' => 'Не валидный URL',
            ),
            'urlRequestValidate' => array(
                'rule' => array('requestUrl', true),
                'message' => 'URL не найден'
            )
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty')
            )
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User'
    );

    public function requestUrl($url) {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);

        return (boolean)get_headers($url['url']);
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

/**
 * User Model
 *
 */
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    public $validate = array(

    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Role'
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'AdPlace',
        'News'
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
            $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
        parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
    }

    public function encryptHash($user = array()) {
        $hash = '';
        if(!empty($user) && isset($user['User'])) {
            $hash = base64_encode(
                    Security::rijndael(serialize($user['User']), Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed'), 'encrypt')
            );
            $hash = preg_replace('/\//', '::', $hash);
        }
        return (string) $hash;
    }

    public function decryptHash($hash = '') {

        if(!empty($hash)) {
            $hash = preg_replace('/::/', '/', $hash);
            $hash = preg_replace('/\s/', '+', $hash);
            $hash = base64_decode($hash);
            $hash = @unserialize(Security::rijndael($hash, Configure::read('Security.cipherSeed'), 'decrypt'));
        }
        return $hash;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your Model code?

Comment: i've added code to the post,

Comment: add in controller debug($this->AdPlace->find('all'));

Comment: You said `When I do $this->Place->find('all'); I see an empty array result`. Is it `AdPlace` or `Place`?

Comment: Is your debug mode set to `0`? Because it should throw an error that the association does not exist. Since the model itself is called `AdPlace`.

Comment: sorry, model called AdPlace and debug (DebugKit) is working fine, and sqllog shows mysql records with joins of adplace and user, but output is empty ^-/